# Cannot connect to Impala on Docker

Tags: linux, database, docker, database-connection, impala

I pulled the image apache/kudu:impala-latest on Docker. And I run a container for this image on Docker.

```
docker pull apache/kudu:impala-latest
docker run -d --name kudu-impala -p 21000:21000 -p 21050:21050 -p 25000:25000 -p 25010:25010 -p 25020:25020 apache/kudu:impala-latest impala
```

The container is up.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXkjY.png)
But when I run the fowowlling command

```
docker exec -it kudu-impala impala-shell
```

it shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B80nS.png)

I do not know why this happened?

When I use DBeave to connect to the Impala, it failed. And shows
[Cloudera]ImpalaJDBCDriver Error initialized or created transport for authentication: Connection timed out: connect.
Connection timed out: connect
Connection timed out: connect

Does it mean that the impala server on Docker doesn't start successfully?
How to solve this problem? I really want to use impala server.

Other information:
My operating system is:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Docker version is:
Docker version 23.0.3, build 3e7cbfd

How to solve this problem? I really want to use impala server

Comment: I looked at the log for the impala server on Docker. Finally I figured out the reason is that

Comment: System memory available: 1.95 GB (from physical mem)
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319723737Z I0414 02:06:24.511713    18 exec-env.cc:499] Using process memory limit: 1.56 GB (--mem_limit=80% of 1.95 GB)
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319730006Z F0414 02:06:24.520639    18 impalad-main.cc:73] Invalid --buffer_pool_limit value, must be a percentage or positive bytes value or percentage: 85%
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319736243Z . Impalad exiting.